# How to center align a <td> in a <tr>?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have the following code, which shows four images in a table. The reason for the `float: left;` CSS is so that they wrap. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4d4cmaa/)

```
<table>
    <tr>

        <td style="float: left; padding: 20px;">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97300&w=600&h=300" />
            <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #1</div>
        </td>

        <td style="float: left; padding: 20px;">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97300&w=600&h=300" />
            <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #2</div>
        </td>

        <td style="float: left; padding: 20px;">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97300&w=600&h=300" />
            <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #3</div>
        </td>

        <td style="float: left; padding: 20px;">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97300&w=600&h=300" />
            <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #4</div>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

However, they currently are fixed to the left of the table row (which is understandable, hence the `float: left` CSS). However, is there a way that I can get the wrapping effect of the floating while having the <td> elements center aligned inside the <tr> element?

And yes, I do have to use a table.

Comment: a simple <span align="center"> after each td opening tag should work, did u test it ?

Comment: I thought `align` as a HTML tag was deprecated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of floating the `td`, you can use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` on the `tr` and that will cause the same behavior. Then you can use `justify-content: center;` to center the `td`'s.

```css
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td style="padding: 20px;">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97300&w=600&h=300" />
      <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #1</div>
    </td>

    <td style="padding: 20px;">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97300&w=600&h=300" />
      <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #2</div>
    </td>

    <td style="padding: 20px;">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97300&w=600&h=300" />
      <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #3</div>
    </td>

    <td style="padding: 20px;">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97300&w=600&h=300" />
      <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #4</div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's almost it, but is there a way to make it still centralised when it's zoomed out? http://i.imgur.com/bM8ClYt.png

Comment: @carefulnow If it fixed your problem and now u wanna centralised the whole table, then u should make changes to your table like tr

Comment: @carefulnow: Just add `margin: auto` to the table.